# Definition of total variation: I cannot grasp its meaning

Tags: real-analysis, definition, total-variation

Starting from this [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Definitions) of Total Variation for a function of one real variable, I cannot understand what it does mean that "supremum runs over set of all partitions".

---

**My interpretation**: 
I have a function $f:x\in(a,b)\mapsto f(x)$, I can figure out infinitely many partitions $P_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=(x_0^n,\ldots,x_i^n)$ of the interval $(a,b)$ such that:

- $$P_1=(x_0^1,\ldots,x_i^1) \text{ has a specific sum  }J_1=\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}|f(x_{j+1}^1)-f(x_j^1)| \text{ associated to itself} \tag{1}$$
- $$P_2=(x_0^2,\ldots,x_i^2) \text{ has a specific sum  }J_2=\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}|f(x_{j+1}^2)-f(x_j^2)| \text{ associated to itself} \tag{2}$$
  $$\vdots$$

Eventually, I compute total variation of $f(x)$ such that:
$$TV(f(x))=\sup(J_1,J_2,\ldots)\tag{3}$$
where $TV$ stands for Total Variation.

---

---

I do not know at all whether my reasoning is correct. If it were so, even if I start from a "larger-mesh" partition $P_1$ and go on with partitions whose mesh is lower than the previous partition mesh, why should I expect that $J_1\ne J_2\ne \ldots$?
I know that maybe my point is very very silly, but I would guess that, whatever the partition is (in terms of mesh length), the sum of the absolute value of step-wise variations of $f$ is always the same, namely that $J_1=J_2=\ldots$
 Hence, my question would be: why taking several partitions and then taking supremum over all such different partitions? Woldn't it suffice to take just one single general partition?

---

---

---

Finally, if I had to graphically imagine what total variation of a real function of one variable is, should I imagine it as the sum of step-wise length of corresponding $y$-axis couple of points?

Sorry in advance if my reasoning ignores very trivial facts.

Comment: Your notation looks odd.  What do you mean by $x_j^2$?  Usually it would mean squared, but that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was suspecting it was a confusing notation @herbsteinberg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot enumerate the set of partitions of $[a,b]$. In other words, there is no list $\{P_1,P_2,\ldots\}$ which consists of all partitions of $[a,b]$. Other than that, you are correct:

1. You consider the set $\mathcal P$ of all partitions of $[a,b]$.
2. For each $P\in\mathcal P$, if $P=\{x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, you compute the sum $\displaystyle J_P=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\bigl|f(x_i)-f(x_{i+1})\bigr|$.
3. Then the total variation of $f$ is $\sup\{J_P\mid P\in\mathcal P\}$.

Concerning your question but whether you could take the sum with respect to a “single general partition”, you will have to explain first what that is. Note that, in general, if $P,P^\star\in\mathcal P$, then $J_P\ne J_{P^\star}$. And, (again, in general) there is no partition $P$ such that the total variation is equal to $J_P$; in other words, that supremum is not, in general, a maximum.

Comment: If I imagine whatever function, I cannot really understand why if $P,P*\in\mathcal{P}$, then $J_P\ne J_{P*}$. Could you please give me a very simple example or something like that?

Comment: It's not true that if $P,P^* \in \mathcal P$ then $J_P \ne J_{P^*}$. And fortunately it's irrelevant. What's relevant is the set of numbers $\{J_P \mid P \in \mathcal P\}$. Who cares if some of the numbers have been listed $42$ times, or even uncountably many times? A number $j \in \mathbb R$ is in that set if there exists $P \in \mathcal P$ such that $j=j_P$, and otherwise that number $j$ is not in the set.

Comment: @Strictly_increasing Take $f\colon[-1,1]\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)=|x|$, take $P=\{-1,1\}$ and take $P^\star=\{-1,0,1\}$. Then $J_P=0$, whereas $J_{P^\star}=2$.

Comment: Great example, thank you a lot for all your help and time